# Using Springboot JpaRepository to get the last element stored in the database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
 @Repository
public interface ThirdPartyRequestLogRepository extends JpaRepository<ThirdPartyRequestLog, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ThirdPartyRequestLog> {

    ThirdPartyRequestLog findTopByBusinessReferenceNumberOrderByIdDesc(String businessReferenceNumber);

} 

 ThirdPartyRequestLog creditApplicationLog = thirdPartyRequestLogRepository.findTopByBusinessReferenceNumberOrderByIdDesc(creditApplication.getBusinessReferenceNumber());
```

I want to get the last element by "business reference number" stored in the table but i'm getting a null. My method `findTopByBusinessReferenceNumberOrderByIdDesc(creditApplication.getBusinessReferenceNumber()` is returning null.

Comment: Can you post the application log (debug mode + log sql queries)?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I'm sorted thanks

Answer (score 1):

findTop1ByBusinessReferenceNumberOrderByIdDesc - Try this out.

Comment: Probably not the problem: According to [limiting query results](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result): _If the number is left out, a result size of 1 is assumed._

Comment: @AbySebastin thanks i tried     ThirdPartyRequestLog findTop1ByBusinessReferenceNumberOrderByIdDesc(String businessReferenceNumber);
and it worked like a charm